# ¿Hay posposiciones en español?

Tags: gramática

Various references (like [this](https://www.lingoda.com/en/content/spanish-prepositions/%20) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_prepositions)) say no. Indeed, according to [1](https://www.lingoda.com/en/content/spanish-prepositions/%20), “the Spanish language does not have postpositions, which function in a similar way to prepositions, but are placed after the object.” On the other hand, [at least one scholar argues otherwise](https://www.jstor.org/stable/343312).

To me, it seems that in a sentence like

> La tienda está calle abajo.

the structure is “NP VP,”
where the VP is “V P’P,”
and P’P is a **post**positional phrase comprising a noun and a postposition.

So I have three (sorry! But they **are** closely related) questions:

1. What, if anything, is wrong with my analysis?
2. What other such postpositions occur (besides the obvious *arriba*)?
3. What kind of patterns govern?

Sadly, I am unable to access more than the first page of [3](https://www.jstor.org/stable/343312).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debemos hacer una distinción entre dos posibles significados de pospocición:

1. Cierto tipo semántico de palabras que enlazan y completan el sentido de relaciones entre sintagmas y que *siempre es obligatorio* ubicarlas después de aquellos sintagmas que hacen de objeto o sujeto.
2. Cualquier sintagma que está pospuesto en relación a otro que va antepuesto.

Según un análisis clásico, la oración se descompondría como:

- 'La tienda' : sujeto
- 'está' : verbo
- 'calle abajo' : adverbio o circunstancial, donde *abajo* es el adverbio propiamente dicho. Es equivalente a reemplazarlo por 'bajando por la calle' o 'yendo hacia abajo por esta calle'.

En este sentido, a lo que te estarías refiriendo es a un adverbio. Es una posposición de acuerdo a la segunda acepción, pero no según la primera. Distinto sería 'bajo la calle', en este caso hay una preposición, pero el significado es diferente.

Lo que se sostiene al decir que en español no hay posposiciones, básicamente sería:

> Hay un cierto tipo de palabras que se llaman preposiciones. Éstas especifican el sentido en el que debe entenderse el sintagma nominal y van siempre antes del mismo. No pueden ir después.

Entonces sí que es cierto que las palabras que caen bajo esta denominación no pueden ser posposiciones. Se dice por ejemplo, 'sobre la calle', y no '*la calle sobre'. Pero reitero que no hay una preposición ni posposición—al menos en la clasificación tradicional—en 'calle abajo'.

Ahora bien, diversos lingüistas—no sólo en el idioma español—han criticado la clasificación tradicional de palabras por diversas razones: excesiva arbitrariedad, no representatividad de la realidad, falta de rigurosidad en los criterios de clasificación, entre otras razones que no vienen al caso. Un ejemplo claro es el invento relativamente nuevo del concepto de *determinante lingüístico*. Así que no es de sorprender el hecho de encontrarse con *papers* en donde se proponga una nueva clasifiación de palabras.

Yo me manejo bastante bien con el concepto de ‘preposición’ y es lo que recomiendo, pero no veo el problema de que te resulte más fácil pensar de acuerdo a una nueva clasificación en donde se proponga una distinción entre ‘preposición’ y ‘posposición’, considerando ‘abajo’ como una posposición en un cierto sentido del término. Lo que importa es, en primer lugar, hablar y escribir bien; y en segundo lugar que nunca va a tener lugar en nuestro idioma un concepto que se defina de acuerdo a la primera acepción de 'posposición' que he presentado.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, muy clara e informativa. Es lamentable que ya no exista en este sitio la "virtud cívica" de votar los buenos aportes.